# Sorting list with linq by multiple parameters

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

How would I sort this table rows by following order using linq orderby function:

1. first by *Business type* == **A01 - Production**
2. second by *Business type* == **A06 - External trade without explicit
   capacity**, where *In Area* == **ME**,   *Out Area* by **alphabet**
3. third by *Business type* == **A06 - External trade without explicit
   capacity**, where *Out Area* == **ME**, *In Area* by **alphabet**
4. fourth by *Business type* == **A02 - Internal trade**
5. fifth by *Business type* == **A04 - Consumption**

[image]

Comment: Is it Linq to Objects, or you are querying database?

Comment: You should try something, and also give us the model. What do mean by `where In Area == ME, Out Area by alphabet` ?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM it means that items with same `A06 - External trade without explicit capacity` are sorted also by area

Comment: In Your case for multiple order you should use Orderby(condition).ThenBy(condition);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is possible to create single query without unions:

```
var query = 
   db.Foos
     .OrderBy(f =>
         f.BusinessType == "A01 - Production" ? 0 :
         f.BusinessType == "A06 - External trade without explicit capacity" ?
           (f.InArea == "ME" ? 1 : (f.OutArea == "ME" ? 2 : 6)) :
         f.BusinessType == "A02 - Internal trade" ? 3 :
         f.BusinessType == "A04 - Consumption" ? 4 : 5)
     .ThenBy(f =>
         f.BusinessType == "A06 - External trade without explicit capacity" ?
             (f.InArea == "ME" ? f.OutArea : 
             (f.OutArea == "ME" ? f.InArea : ""))  : "");
```

If you are using Linq to Objects, then simply provide custom comparer, or override Equals and GetHashCode of your objects.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is what you want to do:

```
var result = 
  input.Where(e => e.BusinessType == "A01 - Production")
       .Concat(input.Where(e => e.BusinessType == "A06 - External trade without explicit capacity" && e.InArea == "ME")
                    .OrderBy(e => e.OutArea))
       .Concat(input.Where(e => e.BusinessType == "A06 - External trade without explicit capacity" && e.OutArea == "ME")
                    .OrderBy(e => e.InArea))
       .Concat(input.Where(e => e.BusinessType == "A02 - Internal trade"))
       .Concat(input.Where(e => e.BusinessType == "A04 - Consumption"));
```